# Split using RegEx in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

Let's say I have a generalized string

```
"...&<constant_word>+<random_words_with_random_length>&...&...&..."
```

I would want to split the string using

```
"<constant_word>+<random_words_with_random_length>&"
```

for which I tried RegEx split like

```
<string>.split(/<constant_word>.*&/)
```

This RegEx splits till the last '&' unfortunately i.e.

```
"<constant_word>+<random_words_with_random_length>&...&...&"
```

What would be the RegEx code if I wanted it to split when it gets the first '&'?

example for a string split like

```
"example&ABC56748393&this&is&a&sample&string".split(/ABC.*&/)
```

gives me

```
["example&","string"]
```

while what I want is..

```
["example&","this&is&a&sample&string"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may change the *greediness* with a question mark `?`:

```
"example&ABC56748393&this&is&a&sample&string".split(/&ABC.*?&/);
// ["example", "this&is&a&sample&string"]
```

Comment: what if I wanted till the second '&', then what will change in the regex code?

Comment: ok then it would be this "example&ABC56748393&this&is&a&sample&string".split(/ABC.*?&.*?&/)

Comment: Alternatively, with less repetition: `/ABC(?:.*?&){2}/`. The `(?:)` just wraps it in a non-capturing group, so it can be treated as a single entity.

Answer (score 2):

Just use non greedy match, by placing a `?` after the `*` or `+`:

```
<string>.split(/<constant_word>.*?&/)
```