# Js advanced string split

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a long string from a .txt-file, containing several sentences and dates that I want to split up.

The syntax is like this

```
01-01-15: Here is some text
02-01-15: Here is some other text
05-06-17: Here is some new text
06-06-17: Here is some text
taking up 
several lines
07-06-17: And so on
```

Since some of the sentences take up several lines I cannot use `text.split("\n")` - but what can I do instead then? 
All sentences start with xx-xx-xx where x is a number.

Comment: You can have a special symbol after at the end of each sentence and split by them

Comment: The Javascript 'split' function as you are using above can take a regular expression to split on (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) .  A quick google should help you if your unfamiliar with the syntax.  If you wish to test there are many regex tester sites (such as http://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633948/javascript-split-string-by-characters-only-or-by-characters-number-if-present

Comment: (How) can you be sure, that the sentences don't contain dates after new lines by chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split using RegEx in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386860/split-using-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the lines by searching for the starting date of each logical unit with a lookahead pattern.

```js
var data = '01-01-15: Here is some text\
02-01-15: Here is some other text\
05-06-17: Here is some new text\
06-06-17: Here is some text\
taking up \
several lines\
07-06-17: And so on';


console.log(data.split(/(?=\d\d-\d\d-\d\d:)/));
```

Comment: Exactly what I came up with, except I used `\d{2}`. `\d\d` is probably clearer.